# Posting a story/message to multiple friends' feed/Wall

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, feed

I have the following JavaScript code to publish/post a message to friend's Wall, as this code publishes to only one friend's Wall. What I am trying to do is, to publish/post one message to multiple friends' Wall. Any help please...!

```
  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.',
      to: 'FRIND_ID'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

Comment: I'd normally close/downvote but as the OP has already tried to ask via an [incorrect edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/205542), posting a Q is better - All we need is a few more details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware that's not possible with the js sdk, unless of course you want to open a dialog per post...

You can however ask for the *publish_stream* and then make the posts on the server side, there you can issue as many posts as you want. Here too you'll be able to send one post at a time, but you can do it more than once without bothering the user with a dialog for every post.

## EDIT

The documentation for permissions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ states:

> **publish_stream**
>
> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes
>   to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this
>   permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time,
>   without requiring offline_access. However, please note that Facebook
>   recommends a user-initiated sharing model.

As for how to do it actually, you tagged this question as "php", and so you should use the facebook php sdk, with that it's pretty simple and straight forward how to do it, and you have the official tutorial: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/ (go to the *Post a link to a User's wall using the Graph API*)

Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Please share a link to perform this task on server side, as I am new to the programming and Facebook Applications.

Comment: The link from where I can get some help!
Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to help, and if this answers your question please be sure to accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I am grateful to you Sir for this help :)
I found this line of code 
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/friend_ID/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'link' => 'www.example.com',
                                      'message' => 'some message'
now I want to publish same link to multiple friends' Wall. To do so, should I loop this line of code or any other approach will do this efficiently?

Comment: You have two options: 1) As you said, looping this request and send one per user, 2) You can use the [Batch Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) to send all of the posts in one http request.

Comment: :) it's working, when I put friendID.
But when I put
$uid='***';
$facebook->api('/$uid/feed'...
then it's not working, I also tried to concatenate the $uid (".$uid .")

Comment: How did you use the batch request? in all of their examples there they use one access token for the whole request, since you are trying to post to more than one user you need to supply access tokens per user, read the section titled "*Specifying different access tokens for different operations*" on the same page.

Comment: I didn't use the batch request, I have an array containing the IDs of my friends. So now I am trying to loop that request to post the link to my friends' wall. I just want to know that how to put the variable $uid in that request! $facebook->api('/FRIEND_ID/feed'... is inside the foreach loop.
I am very Thankful for your guidelines...

Comment: Um, wait, are you trying to post on the wall of the user friends? In order to post on someones wall you need him to grant your application the "publish_stream" permission, and by doing so he only permits you to post to his wall, not to his friends wall. That's why the post to "/me/feed" works, but not the "/$friendId/feed".

Comment: Suppose one of friends ID is 1234, when I put this id directly in this request ('/1234/feed','POST'...) then it publishes the specified link to my friend's Wall. But when I assign this ID to $id ($id=1234) and then I put this variable in this request ('/$id/feed','POST'...), then it throws an exception (code is here this link was given by you in previous comments [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) ) "Post a link to a User's wall using the Graph API"

Comment: Are you doing this: *"/$id/feed"* or *'/$id/feed'*? The first should work fine since in php when you use double quotes it will interpret more escape sequences for special characters, but if you are using the later, that is single quotes, then you can not use it this way, you need to do: *'/'.$id.'/feed'*. Maybe that's your problem? If so, please read about [Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in php.

Comment: yes, this was the problem. It's now working :)
I am thankful to you for this help.

Answer (score 4):

Since February 6th, 2013 Facebook are no longer allowing posting on friends' walls so there is NO WAY to do this anymore. For more info check: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/